# Maintain scroll position in UIWebView when resizing

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIWebView which resizes when the device is rotated. When the webview is resized the scroll position from the top of the page remains the same, but since the height of the content is changing, you end up in a different place at the end of the rotation.

The content of the webview is text and images which are not being scaled to fit. At a smaller width the text breaks more making it taller.

Is there a good way to maintain the scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

One way to kind of work around this problem is to adjust the contentOffset of the webviews's scrollview after a rotation. Due to changes in line breaks in texts the overall size of the page may change during a rotation.

So to solve this, you have to save the old size of the webviews content in the "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation"-method, then calculate the relative change in the "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation"-method and adjust the scrollviews contentOffset. (That 'almost' solve the problem - i say almost because due to the changes in line breaks, you might end up one or two lines off your desired position.)

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    oldSize = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGSize newSize = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    float xFactor = newSize.width / oldSize.width;
    float yFactor = newSize.height / oldSize.height;

    CGPoint newOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
    newOffset.x *= xFactor;
    newOffset.y *= yFactor;

    webView.scrollView.contentOffset = newOffset;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi. That works well if it's just text in the view, but isn't a close enough approximation with most content to solve the issue. The problem with this is that if the content contains both text and images, the height of images decreases (in my situation at least) while the height of text increases. So it's not as simple as scaling it. Varying type size and other elements also cause break linear scaling like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my solution: https://github.com/cxa/WebViewContentPositioner. In short, I use `document.caretRangeFromPoint(0, 0)` to capture the `Range`, and insert an element to track its position. After resizing, use the captured `Range` info to decide position.